# How to have div only show on desktop?

Tags: html, css, desktop

I currently have a div alert that I am using that I would like to only show on a desktop view.

I am using the class `content-desktop` in my container but I am still seeing this div in mobile. How do I show this div only on desktop?

```
 <div class="feedback-container content-desktop" id="alert-dialog">
        <div class="feedback-left">
          <p>Have any feedback? Reach out to us!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="feedback-right">
            <button class="feedback-button">Give Feedback</button>
            <button class="feedback-button">Dismiss</button>
        </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css media queries

```
@media(max-width:991px){
  .content-desktop(
             display:none;
   )
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are gonna need some responsive design code for that. Around 900px should be enough of a limit:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    .yourclass { 
        min 800px
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to make it shown only on displays larger than XXXpx

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .content-desktop {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Here it will be hidden for screen smaller than 767px

You have to add this in a separated CSS file or between style tags